# How to load default model in mvc?

Tags: php

I'm writing an MVC project.

When my URL is empty it has to load the index controller. That part works fine, but I also need it to load an index_model. But I can't load it no matter what I have tried.

My Bootstrap code is here. As you can see I have tried to load it in the `if(empty())` section by doing

```
$controller->loadModel('index');
```

but it does not work. So what to do? Please help me.

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class Bootstrap {

    function __construct() {
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        if(empty($url[0])) {
            require 'controllers/index.php';
            $controller = new Index();
            $controller->index();
            $controller->loadModel('index');
            return false;
        }

        $file = 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        } else {
            $this->cmserror();
        }

        $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if(isset($url[2])) {
            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
            } else {
                $this->cmserror();
            }
        } else {
            if(isset($url[1])) {
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                } else {
                    $this->cmserror();
                }
            } else {
                $controller->index();
            }
        }
    }

    function cmserror() {
        require 'controllers/cmserror.php';
        $controller = new CmsError();
        $controller->index();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug it line by line.And mention the errors in question. Model is not loading is not enough to understand what problem exist.

Answer (score -1):

try this ??
and look at this one i made :
https://github.com/omaraligit/mymvc

```
class Bootstrap {

    function __construct() {
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        //changes are in here 
        $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);
        if(empty($url[0])) {
            require 'controllers/index.php';
            $controller = new Index();
            $controller->index();
            $controller->loadModel('index');
            return false;
        }

        $file = 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        } else {
            $this->cmserror();
        }



        if(isset($url[2])) {
            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
            } else {
                $this->cmserror();
            }
        } else {
            if(isset($url[1])) {
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                } else {
                    $this->cmserror();
                }
            } else {
                $controller->index();
            }
        }
    }

    function cmserror() {
        require 'controllers/cmserror.php';
        $controller = new CmsError();
        $controller->index();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: its a really good idea to point out where the code was wrong, rather than just putting up a 'working' version.  This helps the OP understand where they went wrong.